# Restriction for downloading Source Code from RTC Web Client

Tags: version-control, rtc

Here My scenario, Developers and Testers are part of the Project but only Developers should have rights to download Source Code from the web client whereas Testers should not have rights to download Source Code from the Web client. I checked with Access Control but I didn't get any idea regarding to the scenario. Please suggest some ideas to My scenario.

Regards / Kiran

Answer (score 0):

You can start checking out "[Controlling access to source control artifacts in Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/library/article/215)".
It does list for instance "[Read protect some files or folders within a component but give public access to others](https://jazz.net/library/article/215#protect_some_files)", which could fit your requirements.

> - Drill down and find the sensitive file or folder.
> - Select Change Access Control from the context menu
> - In the resulting dialog, select the Project area or team area option, click Browse and then select the private JUnit Project. Click OK.
>
> The visibility of the file is now dictated by the JUnit Project so only members of that project can see the file.

[image: https://jazz.net/library-content/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/fileperms.png]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is it possible to set like only particular users can able to download source code from rtc web client? Like only developers will have rights to download source code whereas testers can able view/read only source code.

Comment: @kiranananth Check if you can assign users to those "access group"

Comment: In Read Access Permission, I selected Project Area/Team Area and then I chose Team Area to access the component. As a result, only the particular Team Area can able to view the File whereas other Team Area people are able to see the file in the component. In My scenario, everyone in the Project should able to see the file but the particular users eg. testers should not have rights to download the File.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to assign those who are not developers, a contributor license. That provides read only access to all source operations. If you want to remove the link from the web client, you can create a custom theme and add that to the server. This would require working with the HTML/CSS/JS.